# Cannot connect to Google sites in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I have opened  many tabs in Firefox 14.0.1 under Ubuntu 12.04. It takes forever to connect to Google sites including Google search and gmail. Other sites are opened fine in Firefox, and Google sites can be opened immediately in Chrome.

I wonder why? Thanks!

Comment: A cunning plan to get folk to switch to the Google browser?!

Comment: It sounds like you might be using a proxy. Check `Tools→Options→Advanced→Network→Settings`.

Comment: @Synetech: I am not using a proxy. But I am not sure if it has something to do with that I open about 200 tabs already.

Comment: @w3d: Can I say your comment is a cunning plan to get me to stay with Firefox?

Comment: @Tim, it’s certainly possible. Two-hundred tabs is a lot, but if only a few sites are being affected, it might be your ISPs caching/proxy affecting it, or perhaps Google sites just use too much resources (which would certainly be strange since they generally do not; at least not like sites like TV.com which is practically unusable on anything even moderately old due to its abhorrently excessive JavaScript and Flash).

Comment: @Synetech: If it was an issue with the ISP's caching/proxy then wouldn't _all_ browsers be affected? I would have said the 200 tabs is most certainly a contributing factor. I have gone over 100 tabs before and found it unmanageable!

Comment: Maybe it’s a plugin or site-dependent addon. Check to see if you have a bunch of extensions that target Google sites and do a lot of processing with them.

Comment: Please see if this Q is helpful for you: http://superuser.com/questions/64716/i-regularly-see-gstatic-com-in-the-status-bar-what-is-that-domain